# Thesis's title vs Thesis' title

Tags: adjectives

please can someone tell me which one is correct (Thesis's title vs Thesis' title). Or if both options can be used?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the style used, it's currently more common to add an *'s* to any singular noun that ends in *s*. That would make it *thesis's*. (This is what what *The Chicago Manual of Style* prefers—with a few seldom-encountered exceptions). But it used to be that only  a *'* would be added, and it's not uncommon to still find that system being used. (Whichever system you use, make sure you are consistent.)

You can avoid the question by rephrasing it to *title of the thesis*.

However, there is actually no need to use the possessive at all in this particular case—and most people would actually find it odd. You can use *thesis title* as a non-possessive noun in the same way that we use *door knob* rather than *door's knob*.

Comment: Note: I very deliberately wrote a ' above, rather than an '. Why? Because even though when reading it aloud I would say "an apostrophe," when looking at it visually it is just a symbol. And a symbol doesn't "have" a vowel in front of it.

Comment: "Hour" doesn't start with a vowel, yet we still pronounce *and* write "an hour".